# Android Studio - error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded the code from this repository (its a app to control a parrot drone):

[Github](https://github.com/SUPENTA/ardrone-sdk-android)

with the hopes of getting it to work so i can study the code, however im getting this error that seems hard to find a solution after searching the web, i mostly found things for IOS, xcode, etc

I imported the project into android studio, when i try to execute the app i get the following error:

> Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am not really into NDK, but from what i saw it could be the reason, things i tried:

- Downloaded NDK and added the correct path to it.
- Using latest SDK.
- Changes to build.gradle like setting buildToolsVersion "25.0.0", etc

**Build.gradle (Project: ardrone)**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
    import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.parrot.freeflight"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 20000
        versionName "2.0-SDK"

        ndk {
            moduleName "adfreeflight"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            // TODO proguard-rules seem outdated and useless cause it's only Android stuff
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
        // This is not necessary unless you have precompiled libraries in your project.
    }

    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        def ndkCommand = "${android.ndkDirectory}/ndk-build"
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            ndkCommand += ".cmd"
        }

        commandLine ndkCommand,
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                'all',
                'NDK_DEBUG=1'
    }

    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        def ndkCommand = "${android.ndkDirectory}/ndk-build"
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            ndkCommand += ".cmd"
        }

        commandLine ndkCommand,
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                'clean'
    }

    clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.sony.rdis.receiver-20111206.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.sony.rdis.receiver.utility-20111206.jar')
}
```

**local.properties**

```
    ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\BugDroid\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\BugDroid\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Comment: There should be more error text than that one line. Please look at the log and find the descriptive error message, as this is just the generic message from ld.

Comment: How can i see the log ?

Comment: In the log window in Android Studio, if you're building from there.

Comment: I dont get anything else.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check your log for more details as the error '*Linker command failed with exit code 1*' is usually followed by the more detailed error.

So to find more details, in Xcode click on the error under *Buildtime* and choose *Reveal in log*. This should give you extra hint. Without any specific error, it's difficult to know what's the problem.